# Add Seconds to Timestamp from another Timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I got two timestamps:

say:

```
21.10.2013 00:00:23
```

and

```
21.10.2013 00:00:00
```

How can I add the 23 Seconds from timestamp 1 to the second.

My query is something like that at the moment:

```
select count(1) 
from tbl where timestamp1 >= NVL((select MAX(TIMESTAMP2) + ("Seconds from TS 1") 
from tbl2), timestamp - 1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
timestamp2  + (extract (second from timestamp1)/86400)
```

Comment: works very well. sry to bother again, but what if i want to add minutes AND seconds?

Comment: `timestamp2  + (extract (second from timestamp1)/86400) + (extract(minute from timestamp1)/1440)`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could get the seconds (or minutes and seconds, or the whole time portion) from the first timestamp as an [interval](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00200), and add that to the second timestamp.

The [`TRUNC(date)` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm#SQLRF06151) takes a parameter that determines the precision; if you pass `DD` (the default) then it strips the whole time off, if you pass `HH24` then it keeps the hours but strips the minutes and below off, etc. The result is a date, but if you then subtract that from a timestamp the result is an interval ([as the docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208)).

You can see the intervals that are created with this demo:

```sql
with t as (
  select to_timestamp('2013-11-06 09:10:11', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as ts1
  from dual
)
select ts1,
  ts1 - trunc(ts1, 'MI') as second_interval,
  ts1 - trunc(ts1, 'HH24') as minute_interval,
  ts1 - trunc(ts1, 'DD') as hour_interval
from t;

TS1                     SECOND_INTERVAL MINUTE_INTERVAL HOUR_INTERVAL
----------------------- --------------- --------------- -------------
2013-11-06 09:10:11.000 0 0:0:11.0      0 0:10:11.0     0 9:10:11.0
```

You can then add the interval to your other timestamp:

```
with t as (
  select to_timestamp('2013-11-06 09:10:11', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as ts1,
    to_timestamp('2013-10-31 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as ts2
  from dual
)
select ts2 + (ts1 - trunc(ts1, 'MI')) as ts2_second_adj,
  ts2 + (ts1 - trunc(ts1, 'HH24')) as ts2_minute_adj,
  ts2 + (ts1 - trunc(ts1, 'DD')) as ts2_hour_adj
from t;

TS2_SECOND_ADJ          TS2_MINUTE_ADJ          TS2_HOUR_ADJ          
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2013-10-31 00:00:11.000 2013-10-31 00:10:11.000 2013-10-31 09:10:11.000
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9362d/2).

If you're getting more than one part of the time then this might be a bit simpler than doing multiple `extract` calls and having to divide those by the right value (86400 for seconds, etc.). This also retains the fractional seconds from the timestamp, which may or may not be desirable.

This approach [also works for `DATE` values](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9f68/2), while the `extract` version doesn't.